# Publicly available careers CV silently made private?

Tags: feature-request, bug, developer-story

My public SO careers page was the primary part of my professional web presence, referenced all over the place, on printed media, emailed bios and similar places where I have no ability to change the text, (Also, I like the URL).

It seems sometime in the recent round of changes to Careers/Jobs/CVs relating to the developer story, the privacy settings appear to have either silently changed, or the permissions don't allow separate public access for the CV and "developer story" view, (which I disabled due to numerous mistakes caused by discrepancies in section naming which I don't currently have time to fix).

If it was the former I'm pretty sure that's a bug, if the latter, it was not clear in any way that this action could possibly change the privacy settings for the traditional CV view. The public availability of these shouldn't be tied together IMO as, aside from the different names, the new format is very different and the same information needs to be completely rearranged to tell a coherent story.

Relatedly, can we get the ability to change the type of entry on a developer story? What were once "Writing" are now "Blogs and Videos", which is not an accurate label for the research articles I have listed there...

Comment: +1 to both of these points. I now have an authored book listed as a "Blog and Video", which is ridiculous.

Comment: I won't post the slug you used, but your CV still seems to be publicly accessible via the stackoverflow.com/cv/[slug] route (as well as its old location at careers.stackoverflow.com/[slug]).

Comment: @Shog9, yes, I just re-enabled it 5 minutes ago. It seems to be entangled with the DS permissions.

Comment: In the past there was an option to disallow search engine spiders to crawl your CV. Is it possible you had that switched on? As this setting does not exist any more.

Comment: @wimh definitely not: it's always been one of the top results when you Google my name + employer